# Getting "You do not have permission to copy this file" while importing files from Android

Tags: permissions

I'm currently using Ubuntu 12.04 dual booted with Windows 7 and I've downloaded all the restricted extras.

But, still when I try to copy `.mkv` files from my android phone to my hard drive, I'm receiving below error message

> You do not have permission to copy this file

How can I resolve this problem?

Is it due to the use of MTP protocol?

Comment: Does this problem appear under Ubuntu?

Comment: This problem does not appear if I copy the file to hard disk with Windows and then move it to /home with Ubuntu. So I think something is wrong in Ubuntu.

Comment: What directory are you trying to copy the files into when in Ubuntu?

Comment: to "Videos" folder under /home

Comment: You may have to use Terminal to copy the files while invoking `sudo`.

Comment: Failed.
I tried using gksu nautilus. It gives the same error message.

Comment: Stumped. Readable by VLC or other media players?

Comment: No. Same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I thought, a problem due to MTP.
I tried these commands;

```
sudo apt-get install golang fuse git-core libmtp-dev
sudo adduser $USER fuse mkdir /tmp/go
GOPATH=/tmp/go go get github.com/hanwen/go-mtpfs
sudo mv /tmp/go/bin/go-mtpfs /usr/bin
mkdir ~/MyAndrid
```

That installed "go-mtpfs".
Now to mount your android,

```
go-mtpfs ~/MyAndroid &
```

volia! Now you can find your contents at MyAndroid folder in your home directory. If you want to unmount your phone, type

```
fusermount -u ~/MyAndroid
```

That's it.

Comment: Maybe `gvfs-copy` would also work